# A recursive puzzle c++ code

Tags: c++, recursion

A recursive puzzle You have been given a puzzle consisting of a row of squares each containing an integer, like this

The circle on the initial square is a marker that can move to other squares along the row. At each step in the puzzle, you may move the marker the number of squares indicated by the integer in the square it currently occupies. The marker may move either left or right along the row but may not move past either end. For example, the only legal first move is to move the marker three squares to the right because there is no room to move three spaces to the left. The goal of the puzzle is to move the marker to the 0 at the far end of the row. In this configuration, you can solve the puzzle by making the following set of moves:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUz3P.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2aGH.png)

a.  Write an algorithm void SolvePuzzle(int start, int squares[1..n]) that takes a starting position of the marker along with the array of squares. The algorithm should solve the puzzle from the starting configuration and display all moves required to reach the 0 at the end of the sequence. You may assume all the integers in the array are positive except for the last entry, the goal square, which is always zero. The values of the elements in the array must be the same after calling your function as they are beforehand, (which is to say if you change them during processing, you need to change them back!)

```
void SolvePuzzle(int start, int squares[]){

if(squares[start]==0)
return;
else{
    cout<<squares[start]<<" ";
if(squares[start]%2==0)
SolvePuzzle( start+squares[start],squares);
else
SolvePuzzle( start-squares[start],squares);
}


}


int main(){
    int arraytest[] = { 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 0 };
SolvePuzzle(arraytest[0],arraytest);

    return 0;
}
```

i solved like this but i need Correct mistakes in If statement

Comment: What is the question? Please consult the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: The fact that "move right if `squares[start]` is even, left if it's odd" solves this particular instance is a coincidence. It's not a general solution.

Comment: yes i no that , i need the good condition in if statment @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing, even if one could not really tell from your description, is that you don't really know if you have to move left or right to solve the puzzle.

The simplest approach is just try to go left, if it works you solved it, otherwise you go right. This means that you have to change your function, otherwise you cannot really return the right path or the answer.

It may appear like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

bool SolvePuzzle(int squares[], int size,  int position, 
                 std::vector<bool>& go_right_sol){
    if(squares[position]==0){
        return true;
    }
    int leftPos = position - squares[position];
    int rightPos = position + squares[position];
    if(rightPos < size && SolvePuzzle(squares, size, rightPos, go_right_sol)){
        go_right_sol.insert(go_right_sol.begin(), true);
        return true;
    }
    if(leftPos > 0 && SolvePuzzle(squares, size, leftPos, go_right_sol)){
        go_right_sol.insert(go_right_sol.begin(), false);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


int main(){
    int arraytest[] = { 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 0 };
    int arraysize = 10;
    std::vector<bool> solution;
    SolvePuzzle(arraytest, arraysize, 0, solution);
    for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++){
        std::cout << ((solution[i]) ? "right" : "left") << " - ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution and I want a solution to the question void function (void SolvePuzzle(int start, int squares[])) @racco23

Comment: Il you really need to satisfy the `void SolvePuzzle(int start, int squares[])` contract, you can just use my solution as an helper and call it from the inside of this function. Beware that you need to take in the lenght of the array somehow, since a simple int[] won't have this information in C++.